# Exponential formula with adjustable "steepness" and a set maximum

Tags: functions, exponential-function

I'm looking for an exponential formula that can handle the following:

- I will input X, Ymax, S (steepness)
- When X = 0, Y must be 0
- When X = 100, Y must be equal to Ymax

So for example, without handling steepness, I've got
y = Ymax ^ (X / 100)
If it helps, answers can be purely math, or in javascript / python.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by steepness? Also what is the condition that the function should satisfy regarding steepness?

Comment: @sudeep5221 Steepness is the sharpness of the curve itself. S or "steepness" is just a number I would input to control how "steep" the curve is. The lower the steepness, the closer the curve should look like a linear function. And as long as when X = 100, Y ends up being equal to Ymax, I'm happy. Sorry if I wasn't clear about that.

Comment: Does something like $y = y_{\max} \left( \dfrac{x}{100} \right)^s$ work?

Comment: @sudeep5221 Pretty close, however when X=0, Y isn't 0. I think of it like a three point curve. Where the first point is at (0,0). The second point in the middle of the curve and it adjusts how steep and at what point Y starts to ramp up. And the third point being (100,Ymax)

Comment: $y$ is indeed $0$ when $x =0$ since putting $x = 0$ is essentially like multiplying the RHS with $0$. That function satisfies all the properties mentioned in the question.

Comment: Where do you want the "steepness" to happen?  Close to X=100 or X=50 or X=0.  Any function will change from a linear function to close to a "square-wave".  (Infinitely steep rise somewhere between X=0 and X=100.)  @sudeep5221 has a good function if you want the steepness close to X=100.

Comment: sudeep5221 yes that does seem like it should be the case. I must've made an error while putting the function into my graph plotter.
@IanJ Does bring up something I did notice: the rise is close to X=100 and it's making me think that maybe I need a function that gives me more control over when the rise is.  
A three point curve kind of thing maybe, but that's a quadratic and I'm not sure how  I can make sure the max is respected using those without using magic numbers (and even then I'm not certain how to calculate those) If it wasn't evident from this post, my math is rusty at best. Thanks

Comment: @LAZ The suggested function has steepness close to $100$ for $ s >1$ and close to $0$ for $s < 1$. Maybe plotting them would help you give a better idea. Though I agree if you want steepness close to $0$. $s < 1$ might give you the curve you need but $s$ won't be exactly related to steepness.